# Latex Error: environment thepublication undefined

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to add the list of publications in my thesis but it's giving me this error: 'environment `thepublication` undefined'. Am I missing any package? Here is my code below:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,final] {article}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}


\nocite{} 
{  
\begin{thepublication}{99}

\section*{Articles} 
\bibitem{A1} Publication title 1 

\section*{Articles Submitted} 
\bibitem{AS1} Publication title 2

\end{thepublication} 
} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which document class do you use? How and where is the environment `thepublication` defined?

Comment: Sorry I've edited and added article class. Can you please show me how to define the environment and where do I need to define it?

Comment: Maybe you are confusing `thepublication` with `thebibliography`?

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve with your document. E.g., are you trying to generate a document that provides a (long) bibliography with various section-level headings such as "Articles" and "Articles Submitted"? Please elaborate.

Comment: Please also confirm (or refute) the impression that you're looking the bibliography entirely by hand.

Comment: I have never seen a `thepublication` enviornment. If you have some documentation that tells you to use that environment, it presumably told you how to define it. It is not a standard environment.

Comment: I'm actually trying to add a 'list of publications' section in my thesis (articles I've published or submitted). I already have bibliography section. Would much appreciate if you could show me any way. I saw ' 'thepublication' environment environment but it didn't work for me as you said it's not standard.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for your comments, it gave me an idea what do I need to do. I've defined `thepublication` environment but it's giving me this error: "undefined control sequence." Should I edit my question and include the code? Thanks again.

Comment: Please add your definition of `thepublication` environment to your post, thank you!

Comment: I've updated my post, please.

Comment: Please either post your solution as an answer (rather than as an edit to the question) or delete the question (since it's unlikely to be of use to anyone else). If you just leave the question without an answer folks may waste time on it better spent otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the people who commented on my post that gave me the idea what I need to do to solve my problem. I needed to define `thepublication` environment to add the list the publications. Here is the environment that I've defined as follows

```
\def\thepublication#1{\chapter*{\pubname\@mkboth
{\uppercase{\pubname}}{\uppercase{\pubname}}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\pubname}
\list{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}{\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
\leftmargin\labelwidth
\advance\leftmargin\labelsep
\usecounter{enumiv}%
\let\p@enumiv\@empty
\def\theenumiv{\arabic{enumiv}}}%
\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus.33em minus.07em}%
\sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
\sfcode`\.=\@m}

\def\endthepublication{%
\def\@noitemerr{\@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
\endlist}
```

}

But it gave me error: 'undefined control sequence'. I defined `pubname`, where I have defined the environment, to remove the error `\pubname` as follows

```
\def\pubname{Publications}
```

That solves my problem.